# Filter table as per the multiple dropdown selection

Tags: javascript, python, html, django, datatable

I have created the table using datatables. I want to filter the table as per the multiple dropdown selection.
But I have multiple tables with the same data. Actually the columns are too much, so to avoid so scrolling I have added the tables into multiple tabs.

```
Like: In TAB1 (columns : ID, Origin, Destination) | TAB2 (columns : ID , Driver Type, Product Type) etc..
```

Here is my dropdown HTML code:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
    
    <div class="input-group mb-6">
      <span style="padding: 4px 10px ;">Route Volume ></span>
      <input type="number" id="filterByVolumeAddOne" class="form-control" style="max-width: 80px; padding: 1px;margin-right: 1em;" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">


      <select class="form-control ml-3" style="width: 15em !important; margin-left: 10px !important;" id="productFilterDropdown" multiple>
        {% for op in products %}
        <option value="{{op.product_name}}">{{op.product_name}}</option>
        {% endfor %}
      </select>
      
      <select class="form-control ml-3" style="width: 20em !important;" id="equipmentFilterDropdown" multiple>
        {% for op in Equipments %}
        <option value="{{op.equipment_name}}">{{op.equipment_name}}</option>
        {% endfor %}
      </select>

      <select class="form-control ml-3 mr-3" style="width: 15em !important;" id="driverFilterDropdown" multiple>
        {% for op in drivers %}
        <option value="{{op.driver_type}}">{{op.driver_type}}</option>
        {% endfor %}
      </select>


        <div class="input-group-prepend">
          <span class="input-group-text" id="filterByVolumeGreater" style="background-color: #2980b9; color: aliceblue; padding: 6px; cursor: pointer;"><i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i></span>
        </div>
     
     
     
    </div>
  </div>

  </div>
```

Table HTML code of TAB1:

```
<table class="table dataTable table-striped table-bordered" id="routeData">
            <thead class="thead-dark">
              <tr>
                <th style="z-index: 2 !important;"></th>
                <th style="z-index: 2 !important;">OPCO</th>
                <th style="z-index: 2 !important;">Route ID</th>
                <th>Origin</th>
                <th>Destination</th>
                <th>Product Type</th>
                <th>Business Segment</th>
                <th>Transport Type</th>
                <th>Transport Movement Type</th>
                <th>Annual Volume</th>
                <th>Freight Cost/Unit</th>
                <th>Action</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              {% for d in route_obj.itertuples %}
              <tr id="{{d.id}}">
                <td style="background-color: white !important;" class="id">{{forloop.counter}}</td>
                <td style="background-color: white !important;">
                  <span class="editSpan route_opco">{{d.opco__opco_name}}</span>
                  <select class="form-control editInput route_opco" name="route_opco" style="display: none; width: max-content !important;">
                    {% for c  in opco %}
                      <option value="{{c}}">{{c}}</option>
                    {% endfor %}
                  </select>
                <small class="text-danger" id="err-route_opco"></small>
                </td>
                <td style="background-color: white !important;">
                  <span class="editSpan routeid">{{d.routeid}}</span>
                  <input class="form-control editInput routeid" type="text" id="routeid" name="routeid" value="{{d.routeid}}" style="display: none; width: max-content !important;"> 
                  <small class="text-danger" id="err-routeid"></small>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <span class="editSpan origin">{{d.source}}</span>
                  <input class="form-control editInput origin" type="text" id="origin" name="origin" value="{{d.source}}" style="display: none; width: max-content !important;"> 
                  <small class='text-danger' id='err-origin'></small>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <span class="editSpan destination">{{d.destination}}</span>
                  <input class="form-control editInput destination" type="text" name="destination" id="destination" value="{{d.destination}}" style="display: none; width: max-content !important;"> 
                  <small class='text-danger' id='err-destination'></small>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <span class="editSpan product_type">{{d.product_id_id__product_name}}</span>
                  <select class="form-control editInput product_type" name="product_type" style="display: none; width: max-content !important;">
                    {% for c  in product_type %}
                    <option {% if c.product_name == d.product_id_id__product_name %} selected="selected" {% endif %} value="{{c.product_name}}">{{c.product_name}}</option>
                    {% endfor %}
                  </select>
                  <small class='text-danger' id='err-product_type'></small>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <span class="editSpan business_Segment">{{d.product_id_id__business_id__name}}</span>
                  <select class="form-control editInput business_Segment" name="business_Segment" style="display: none; width: max-content !important;">
                    {% for c  in business_segment %}
                    <option {% if c.business_segment__name == d.business_Segment %} selected="selected" {% endif %} value="{{c.business_segment__name}}">{{c.business_segment__name}}</option>
                    {% endfor %}
                  </select>
                  <small class='text-danger' id='err-business_Segment'></small>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <span class="editSpan transport_movement_type">{{d.transport_movement_type}}</span>
                  <input class="form-control editInput transport_movement_type" type="text" id="transport_movement_type" name="transport_movement_type" value="{{d.transport_movement_type}}" style="display: none; width: max-content !important;">
                  <small class='text-danger' id='err-transport_movement_type'></small>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <span class="editSpan transport_type">{{d.transport_type}}</span>
                  <input class="form-control editInput transport_type" type="text" id="transport_type" name="transport_type" value="{{d.transport_type}}" style="display: none; width: max-content !important;">
                  <small class='text-danger' id='err-transport_type'></small>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <span class="editSpan annual_volume">{{d.annualVolume}}</span>
                  <input class="form-control editInput annual_volume" type="number" id="annual_volume" name="annual_volume" value="{{d.annualVolume}}" style="display: none; width: max-content !important;">
                  <small class='text-danger' id='err-annual_volume'></small>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <span class="editSpan freight_cost">{{d.freightCost}}</span>
                  <input class="form-control editInput freight_cost" type="number" id="freight_cost" name="freight_cost" value="{{d.freightCost}}" style="display: none; width: max-content !important;">
                  <small class='text-danger' id='err-freight_cost'></small>
                </td> 
                <td> 
                  <i class='fa fa-edit editRoteInfoBtn' style="cursor: pointer;"></i>
                  <i class='fa fa-trash pl-3 deleteRouteBtn' style="cursor: pointer;"></i>
                  <!-- <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary editBtn">Edit</button>
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary deleteBtn">Delete</button>-->
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-success saveRouteInfoBtn" style="display: none;">Save</button>
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger confirmRouteBtn" style="display: none;">Confirm</button>
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary cancelRouteBtn" style="display: none;">Cancel</button>
                </td>
                
              </tr>
              {% endfor %}
            </tbody>
          </table>
```

How can I filter all tabs tables when I select any filter options?
I tried with the datatables API search function but it doesn't work.

Here you can see the frontend:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try like this, Make sure you have included the DataTables library and initialized all tabbed tables as DataTables objects. For example, you can initialize them like this:

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#routeData').DataTable();
    // Initialize other tables here if needed
});
```

Add an event that will trigger when you change the filter in your dropdown selections. For example, you can use the change event to capture changes in your selections:

```
$('#productFilterDropdown, #equipmentFilterDropdown, #driverFilterDropdown').on('change', function() {
    // Here, add the code to apply the filter to all tables
    // You can get the selected values from the dropdown selections
    var selectedProducts = $('#productFilterDropdown').val();
    var selectedEquipments = $('#equipmentFilterDropdown').val();
    var selectedDrivers = $('#driverFilterDropdown').val();

    // Apply the filter to all tables
    $('#routeData').DataTable().column(5).search(selectedProducts.join('|'), true, false).draw();
    // Apply the filter to other tables if needed

    // Make sure to set the correct column number (5 in my example) and handle all tables.
});
```

This code listens for changes in the dropdown selections and applies the filter to the desired columns in all DataTables. You'll need to customize the column number (in my example, it's 5) to match the column where you want to apply the filter in your tables.

Ensure that you apply this code to all tables in the tabs if you have more than one. I hope this helps you, farewell

Comment: Hi @Dave Thanks for your answer. but it doesn't work for me.